# OpenZeppelin - how to check the owner's address of an Ownable token

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

Please excuse this basic question, as I am quite new to this. I created a sample token using OpenZeppelin framework. The token class inherits MintableToken which in turn inherits Ownable. This class has a variable:

```
address public owner;
```

which is by default set to msg.sender, but how do i check the address of this owner using web3js/truffle. I've tried this:

```
coinInstance = testCoin.at("address")
coinInstance.owner
```

but i only get the following

```
{ [Function]
  call: [Function],
  sendTransaction: [Function],
  request: [Function: bound ],
  estimateGas: [Function] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, but figured it out! Since `owner` is a public address, Solidity automatically creates a [getter function](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters), which you have to call like so:

```
coinInstance = testCoin.at("address")
coinInstance.owner()
```

That will return a Promise that should resolve to the owner address.